# Reduce the react native ios/android size folder

Tags: javascript, react-native

Need help to reduce the react-native file size, my repo is getting heavy.

```
cd ios
xcodebuild clean

cd android
./gradlew clean
./gradlew cleanBuildCache
```

I tried both commands but still the same.

node_modules is already in `.gitignore`

[image]

Comment: Please add context, file architecture that is readable in order for us to help

Comment: please see image attached

Comment: The image attached has a popup covering the file architecture..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to add android/app/build which occupies most of space. These get generated when "run android" command is executed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).